# Hello, anyone able to direct me to a "cheat sheet" of Neural Network equations with legends?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, cnn, backpropagation

Can anyone here can direct me to a site that provides a cheat sheet of equations for Neural Networks with a legend for the notation?

It can be on any and all aspects of NN, be it forward or back propagation, activation function, CNN, RNN etc.

I have some reading material with the equations and I have worked through them.  I am looking for a site that breaks it down by notation by legend.

For example, without posting a specific equation, a landing page/cheat sheet that identifies each element in the equation, such as: b= bias
w= weight  a=activation the signification of what numbers are vectors in the equation etc.

I work through equations but find most literature lacking in descriptions within the equation, which makes it difficult for someone who is trying to refresh their linear algebra and calculus.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found out [this](https://stanford.edu/%7Eshervine/teaching/cs-229/) to be quite torough. I can't find their pdf version anymore but they seems to cover what you are looking for (see deep learning for NN equations).

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was looking for.  Appears to be enough notation above and beyond what I've picked up from Andrew Ng's course (from the same school as it were) to really refresh and reinforce the math behind it.  Regards.

Answer (score 1):

Look further for the "zoo neural network posters"
[image: zoo neural network poster]

Comment: I am thinking more along the lines of mathematical equations.  I appreciate this response, but looking more for, as an example:  Y ≈ wo + w1 x  (Y=output, w0=weight, w1=weight, x=input)  etc.